# When do items in the Pipeline call fit_transform(), and when do they call transform()? (scikit-learn, Pipeline)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit a model that I've put together using Pipeline:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

cross_validation_object = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(Y, n_folds = 10)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = [0,1])
logistic_fit = LogisticRegression()

pipeline_object = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),('model', logistic_fit)])

tuned_parameters = [{'model__C': [0.01,0.1,1,10],
                    'model__penalty': ['l1','l2']}]

grid_search_object = GridSearchCV(pipeline_object, tuned_parameters, cv = cross_validation_object, scoring = 'accuracy')

grid_search_object.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

My question: Is the best_estimator going to scale the test data based on the values in the training data?  For example, if I call:

```
grid_search_object.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

It will NOT try to fit the scaler on the X_test data, right?  It will just transform it using the original parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `predict` methods never fit any data. In this case, exactly as you describe it, the `best_estimator_` pipeline is going to scale based on the scaling it has learnt on the training set.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Would be great if you could add any source that proofs your claim.